# Extracting data using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following string, how would I extract the string between the quotes that follows data-selected (i.e. THIS-DATA).  I would like it to work regardless of whether single or double quotes are used, or whether there is any white-space before or after the equal sign.  Thank you

```
<td><img alt="abc" src="lib/templates/administrator/images/star.png" data-selected="THIS_DATA" title="None" class="vtip"></td>
```

Comment: [You can't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/538551)

Comment: @tjameson.  I thought you could search until you found a given pattern (i.e. data-selected), then gobble up until a next pattern was found.

Comment: I read that post earlier and thought it was hilarious. That's all.

Comment: Wow, that was quite a post!

Comment: @user1032531 so you're getting a string that starts with a td tag...quite unusual!

Comment: @Christophe.  Actually, just the text inside the td tag.

Comment: is this really a javascript question? You woulndn't use a regex to parse data attributes in js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple regex, assuming `THIS_DATA` doesn't contain quotes:

```
var reg = /data-selected\s*=\s*["']([^"']*)["']/;
```

To use:

```
function extractData(yourString) {
    var match = str.match(yourString);
    return match ? match[1] : "";
}
```

**Edit:**

Or even simpler:

```
var data = str.replace(/.*data-selected\s*=\s*["']([^"']*)["'].*/, "$1");
```

Comment: Thanks tjameson.  Thanks, let me test it out.  I really need to better learn regex!

Comment: `$1` is the first parenthesized part of the regex (the part we're after). I just made sure the regex matched the entire line (note the `.*` at the beginning and end) so the replace would just extract the part you want. `["']` matches a single or double quote, `[^"']` matches everything else. Happy regexing!

Comment: Thanks again.  I am sure this will work and will select it as the answer, but it will probably first take me an hour to get it working!

Comment: Use the jQuery example then. Still don't understand why you would ever use regex to parse html, when there are already both jQuery and native solutions that are bulletproof.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use jQuery? Not sure why you need to use a regex.

```
var $el = $(".vtip");
var data = $el.attr('data-selected');
```

or native javascript:

```
var el = document.querySelector(".vtip");
var data = el.getAttribute('data-selected');
```

or native javascript with dataset:

```
var el = document.querySelector(".vtip");
var data = el.dataset.selected;
```

More info using dataset:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.dataset

Comment: Thanks Chovy.  Creative solution! Unfortunately, I am unable to use jQuery or similar approach, but just needed a regex.  If the desire for single quotes or whitespace prevents this, I can eliminate these requirements.

Comment: I am creating a jQuery plugin.  When configuring it, user can specify parsing function on certain items.  I am looking for a generic approach to parse the data.

Answer (score 0):

You may parse string as a dom

```
var xmlStr = '<td><img alt="abc" src="lib/templates/administrator/images/star.png" data-selected="THIS_DATA" title="None" class="vtip"></td>';
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");

var path = 'img/@data-selected';

var nodes = xmlDoc.evaluate(path, xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);


var result = nodes.iterateNext();
var data-selected  = result.textContent;
```